# How can I configure bazel tests to run a docker container in a bitbucket pipeline?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, bitbucket, bazel, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a bitbucket pipeline that runs a set of tests via bazel, some of which need to invoke docker commands (integration tests).

When I run this pipeline, I get this error:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Things I've verified:

- The tests pass locally (i.e. not running in the pipeline)
- The `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable is being correctly set in the pipeline

My `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file has the docker service specified for the step with bazel like so:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        services:
          - docker
        script:
          - bazel test //...
```

I would expect this configuration to be sufficient for the tests to run correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out bazel does ***not*** pass environment variables through to tests by default.

Here's the fix:

`bazel test --action_env=DOCKER_HOST //...`

https://bazel.build/docs/user-manual#action-env